# Adding tawk.to code just before body tag on functions.php file

Tags: php, functions, javascript, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I would like to add tawk.to widget script just before the body tag. I would like to add the code to the functions.php file of my child theme. How can I do this? A code sample will assist a long way. The following is my code:

```
    <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5b54359ee21878736ba23110/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can the code to head or before body tag this way. Add this code at the last of `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    ?>
    <!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date(); (function(){ var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s1.async=true; s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/5b54359ee21878736ba23110/default'; s1.charset='UTF-8'; s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*'); s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0); })();
    </script>
    <?php
} );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: if it helped. please upvote or accept the answer by clicking that tick icon. It would really help me.